# I am getting an error that says the method in my module is not a function. Not sure why. I declared another method the same way and it works fine

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an error when I click the button in this application. I am told that the addItem method I declared is not a function. Not sure why. The other module is working fine. I am getting an error that says the method in my module is not a function. Not sure why. I declared another method the same way and it works fine.

```js
// MODULE 1
var UIController = (function() {

 var DOMstrings = {
  inputType: '.add__type',
  inputDescription: '.add__description',
  inputValue: '.add__value',
  inputBtn: '.add__btn'
 }
 
 return{
   
  getInput: function() {

   return {

    type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
    description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
    value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
   }
  },

  getDOMstrings: function() {  
   return DOMstrings;    
  } 
 };

})();

// MODULE 2
var budgetController = (function() {

 // private section
 var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
  this.id = id;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
 }
 
 var Income = function(id, description, value) {
  this.id = id;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
 }
 
 var data = {
       
  allItems: { 
   exp: [],
   inc: [],    
  },
       
  totals: {   
   exp: 0,
   inc: 0    
  }     
 };
 
 // public section
 return {
 
  test: 'test',
  
  // if someone calls this method, it creates a new INSTANCE based on either the Expense || Income OBJECT
  addItem: function(type, des, val) {
  
   // declares the vars used by the method
   var newItem, ID;
  
   // we want the ID value to be = to the last ID value + 1
   // the value of ID is equal to the value in the allItems property of the data object
   // the value in that property is equal to 
   // the length of the value in the allItems property of the data object, minus 1
   
   // Create new ID
   if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {  
    // var ID = data.allItems[type][ data.allItems[type].length - 1 ].id + 1;
    ID = data.allItems[type][ data.allItems[type].length - 1 ].id + 1;   
   } else {   
    ID = 0;   
   }

   // Create
   if (type === 'exp') { 
     // the method is what creates I. using the FC/P above
    newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
   } else if (type === 'inc') {
    // the method is what creates an I. if the Income FC/P above
    newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
   }
   
   // Pushes it into the above data structure
   data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
   
   // returns the new element
   return newItem;
  }
 };
 
});

// MODULE 3
var globalController = (function(UICtrl,budgetCtrl) {
 
 // declares vars.
 var budget, input, newItem;

 function setupEventListeners() { // (3) 
  var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();
  document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', function() {
   ctrlAddItem();
  });

  document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 13) { 
    ctrlAddItem();
   }
  });
 };

 function ctrlAddItem() { // (4)
   
  // 1. Get input values
  input = UICtrl.getInput();
  console.log(input);

  // 2. Add the new item to our data structure/budget controller
  // newItem = BDCtrl.addItem();
  budget = budgetCtrl.addItem();
  console.log(budget);

  // input.type, input.description, input.value      
  // 3. Add the new item to the UI     
  // 4. Calculate budget   
  // 5. Display the budget on the UI 
 }
      
 return { 
  init: function() { // (2)
   console.log('Application has started.');
   setupEventListeners();
  }    
 }
})(UIController,budgetController);

globalController.init(); // (1)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Budgety</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
  <!-- the first section where the outcome is displayed -->
        <div class="top">
            <div class="budget">
                <div class="budget__title">
                    Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>
                
                <div class="budget__income clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
                        <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
                    <div class="right clearfix">
                        <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
                        <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- the second section where the data is inputted -->
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="add">
                <div class="add__container">

     <!-- the 'type' input field -->
                    <select class="add__type">
                        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
                        <option value="exp">-</option>
                    </select>
     
     <!-- the 'add description' input field -->
                    <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
     
     <!-- the 'value' input field -->
                    <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
                    <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
   <!-- the Income/Expenses section of the webpage is divided into 2 parts -->
            <div class="container clearfix">
    
    <!-- the 'income' side -->
                <div class="income">
                    <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>
                    
                    <div class="income__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <!-- the 'expenses' side -->
                <div class="expenses">
                    <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>
                    
                    <div class="expenses__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        
        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like calling `budgetCtrl` **returns** an object that has a method called `addItem`. `addItem` isn't a method of `butdgetCtrl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`budgetCtrl` **returns** an object that has a method called `addItem`. `addItem` isn't a method of `butdgetCtrl`.

You have to call `budgetCtrl` and then you can call `addItem` on the returned object as shown below.

```
budgetCtrl().addItem();
```

After getting by that, you have a different error though and will need to sort that out.

```js
// MODULE 1
var UIController = (function() {

 var DOMstrings = {
  inputType: '.add__type',
  inputDescription: '.add__description',
  inputValue: '.add__value',
  inputBtn: '.add__btn'
 }
 
 return{   
  getInput: function() {
   return {
    type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
    description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
    value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
   }
  },

  getDOMstrings: function() {  
   return DOMstrings;    
  } 
 };

})();

// MODULE 2
var budgetController = (function() {

 // private section
 var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
  this.id = id;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
 }
 
 var Income = function(id, description, value) {
  this.id = id;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
 }
 
 var data = {
       
  allItems: { 
   exp: [],
   inc: [],    
  },
       
  totals: {   
   exp: 0,
   inc: 0    
  }     
 };
 
 // public section
 return {
 
  test: 'test',
  
  // if someone calls this method, it creates a new INSTANCE based on either the Expense || Income OBJECT
  addItem: function(type, des, val) {
  
   // declares the vars used by the method
   var newItem, ID;
  
   // we want the ID value to be = to the last ID value + 1
   // the value of ID is equal to the value in the allItems property of the data object
   // the value in that property is equal to 
   // the length of the value in the allItems property of the data object, minus 1
   
   // Create new ID
   if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {  
    // var ID = data.allItems[type][ data.allItems[type].length - 1 ].id + 1;
    ID = data.allItems[type][ data.allItems[type].length - 1 ].id + 1;   
   } else {   
    ID = 0;   
   }

   // Create
   if (type === 'exp') { 
     // the method is what creates I. using the FC/P above
    newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
   } else if (type === 'inc') {
    // the method is what creates an I. if the Income FC/P above
    newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
   }
   
   // Pushes it into the above data structure
   data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
   
   // returns the new element
   return newItem;
  }
 };
 
});

// MODULE 3
var globalController = (function(UICtrl,budgetCtrl) {
 
 // declares vars.
 var budget, input, newItem;

 function setupEventListeners() { // (3) 
  var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();
  document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', function() {
   ctrlAddItem();
  });

  document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 13) { 
    ctrlAddItem();
   }
  });
 };

 function ctrlAddItem() { // (4)
   
  // 1. Get input values
  input = UICtrl.getInput();
  console.log(input);

  // 2. Add the new item to our data structure/budget controller
  // newItem = BDCtrl.addItem();
    
    // You have to call budgetCtrl and get back the return value ***********
  budget = budgetCtrl().addItem(); 
  console.log(budget);

  // input.type, input.description, input.value      
  // 3. Add the new item to the UI     
  // 4. Calculate budget   
  // 5. Display the budget on the UI 
 }
      
 return { 
  init: function() { // (2)
   console.log('Application has started.');
   setupEventListeners();
  }    
 }
})(UIController,budgetController);

globalController.init(); // (1)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Budgety</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
  <!-- the first section where the outcome is displayed -->
        <div class="top">
            <div class="budget">
                <div class="budget__title">
                    Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>
                
                <div class="budget__income clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
                        <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
                    <div class="right clearfix">
                        <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
                        <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- the second section where the data is inputted -->
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="add">
                <div class="add__container">

     <!-- the 'type' input field -->
                    <select class="add__type">
                        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
                        <option value="exp">-</option>
                    </select>
     
     <!-- the 'add description' input field -->
                    <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
     
     <!-- the 'value' input field -->
                    <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
                    <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
   <!-- the Income/Expenses section of the webpage is divided into 2 parts -->
            <div class="container clearfix">
    
    <!-- the 'income' side -->
                <div class="income">
                    <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>
                    
                    <div class="income__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <!-- the 'expenses' side -->
                <div class="expenses">
                    <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>
                    
                    <div class="expenses__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        
        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure why that is happening, it isnt happening with the other modules. Now im not sure why it doesnt like the .length attached to the arrays.

Comment: Whatever you are calling `.length` on, it isn't an array. That's why you are getting the error. You should log whatever it is you are calling `.length` on to find out.